# HTTPS all requests on cloudfront via CNAME integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to go full HTTPS, have no problem with the main site, but have problem with `CNAME` `cdn.example.com` which is my Amazon cloudfront distribution domain.

I went through all documentation I could find on AWS, but cannot find anything that could help me.

My distribution uses default wildcard cloudfront certificate.

I also have wildcard cert for my domain.

Any suggestions please

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Hello Matt, thanks, but I have managed to fix it with, all I had to do is to get AWS ssl and assign it in cloudfront